# after read(signalfd), does it need a call to waitid()?

Tags: c, linux, signals

Does a call to read() on a signalfd conssume the SIGCHLD?
Or does I need to conssume with waitid() call after?

I received readable event on signalfd by a call to epoll_wait(), Then I do a read() on signalfd, that give all informations needed in signalfd_siginfo.
I loop on read() until return -1 and errno=EAGAIN.
But with the shell command ps aux, processes are still here with `<defunct>`.

If I loop with waitid() I don't have the problem.
Why I need waitid() call after read(signalfd) ?

I can't see this behavior in manpages and I can't find source example on that.

Comment: Rather than a prose description of your code, a [mre] of actual code will convey your situation much more effectively.

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but I think `signalfd` is intended to replace `sigaction`, not to replace `wait`.  You always had to call `wait` inside a SIGCHLD handler, so likewise you have to call `wait` after you get a SIGCHLD notification from a signalfd.

Comment: `waitid` does not "consume the SIGCHILD", it simply retrieves the state of the terminated child.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, read() instead of waitid() you means? why not conssume as read() on timerfd

Comment: @DavidBonnin I'm not sure I understand your comment.  If you `read` the file descriptor created by `signalfd`, I suppose you could say you have "consumed the SIGCHILD".  But `waitid` does not do that.  `waitid` is to be used after you have read the signalfd_siginfo structure from the file descriptor to retrieve the state of the terminated child.  If you con't retrieve that state, the child will be a zombie and the state will remain in the output of `ps` until it is reaped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `wait` on getting `SIGCHLD` from signalfd. This is clearly evidenced by your `<defunct>` output from `ps`.

If you don't ever care about child process return codes, set `SIGCHLD` to be handled by `SIG_IGN`. No more zombies.

Comment: I already have return codes of child with read(). It's same informations as obtain with waitid(). So waitid() serve only as conssume child, not getting informations. It could be more efficient and more coherent to conssume directly by the read() "a bit like read timerfd".

Comment: @DavidBonnin: What could be and what is are two different things.